# Run VBScript from cmd and send input to dialog

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, vbscript

I want to launch a VBScript from a windows xp command promt enter a value to the first box that pops up from the vbsscript.

What I have tried (Want to enter value 2 to the script):

```
START CScript C:\vbscript.vbs 2
START CScript C:\vbscript.vbs < 2
```

None does work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need to see the script to be sure, but I suspect that you need to change the script to use the WScript.Arguments collection insted of opening a dialog box.

Comment: I can't edit the script.

Comment: Then you can't do what you want. At least not in  batch file. You could use another scripting language like AutoIt or a programming language like C# to grab the dialog box and enter the information, but not a batch file.